# How to insert images when signing an office document with POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, digital-signature, xml-signature

I am using Apache POI to sign a word file , here is the sample code :
[signing a file](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html)

While the effect maybe not such intuitive , so I want to add an image like stamp when signing .

I also found that some code to insert a image like this :
[Demonstrates how to add pictures in a .docx document](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/examples/SimpleImages.java)

So does it mean that I need to do this with two individual operations?

Can the insert image operation as a part in signing ?

Comment: Please make clear to yourself what exactly is needed. The signing part of `apache poi` you have referenced does something like [Add invisible digital signatures ...](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-a-digital-signature-in-office-files-70d26dc9-be10-46f1-8efa-719c8b3f1a2d#__toc311526848). But if the need is [Create a signature line ...](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-a-digital-signature-in-office-files-70d26dc9-be10-46f1-8efa-719c8b3f1a2d#__toc311526845) then no, there is not something like this supported by `apache poi` until now.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you , I think the signature line looks like what I need . If the apache poi doesn't support this . Do you know about other Java library to do something like this ?

Comment: What's wrong with individual operations (first adding the image, then saving the docx to file/byte buffer, then signing)?
You could check with Aspose cells if they have the one operation approach ...